# MS ACCESS 3 sections in a form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

How to create a split form like [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjvibip1_XTAhULHJQKHZspD8kQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fmsinc.com%2Fmicrosoftaccess%2Fcontrols%2Fcomponents%2Fsplliter-bar%2Findex.html&psig=AFQjCNHIxTSZASH3z6joJpoEwVXJpMtvBQ&ust=1495067684569656) which has 3 sections (2 tables and 1 form sections?

I can only do the form section and a table below. how to add one more table?

Comment: You could use subforms.  So you'd have a Parent form and 2x subforms.  Or a Parent form and 3x subforms.

Comment: That image shows a form with 2 subforms. The subforms are set for Datasheet view. The splitter bar demonstrated is a custom control that site is selling.